# Acro package: how to insert line w/ words "Acronym" and "Page" before the list of acronyms

Tags: acro

In my LaTex paper, I have a list of acronyms to be displayed on a separate page, which is titled "List of acronyms". I am looking for solution that would replicate my List of Illustrations page, where a line is inserted with words "Figure" and "Page" right after the title and just before the list itself.

My elaborations on this project so far produced this latex code (see below).

I use `acro` package for my acronyms.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Set the page margins as required
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}     % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing % Double space 
\usepackage{endnotes}     % All notes 2b place at a separate section 'Endnotes'
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{acro}         % Acronyms/abbreviations
\include{00-Acronyms}     % List of acronyms, 2b updated
%--> acro manual: https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf
% Managing sections
\usepackage{titlesec}     % To modify the section titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % CHAPTER 1 [New Line] TITLE
\titleformat{\section}[display]            % each chapter has two lines...
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter}{\MakeUppercase{Chapter~\thesection}}{0pt}{}
% Capitalizing the titles of the respective sections:
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Endnotes}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Contents}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{References}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Illustrations}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}
\usepackage{tocloft}      % <-- ...to modify ToC, LoF, and LoT
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % ToC = Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoF = List of Figures
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoT = List of Tables
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\usepackage{natbib}       % Bibliography management
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
% My info
\date{October 14th, 2023}

% ----- Start of the document --------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% All notes to be in the separate section 'Endnotes'
\let\footnote=\endnote

% Table of Contents + making TOC not in bold font
{\let\bfseries\mdseries \tableofcontents} \newpage

% List of Figures/Illustrations
\listoffigures 
\addtocontents{lof}{{~Figure}~\hfill{Page}\par} % <- inserting a line w/"Figure"
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Illustrations}}
\newpage

% List of Tables
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{{~Table}~\hfill{Page}\par} % <- inserting a line w/ "Table"
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Tables}}
\newpage 

% List of Acronyms/Abbreviations
\printacronyms[pages = {display=all,seq/use=false},
           name  = \uppercase{List of Acronyms}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Acronyms}}

%
% ... some latex code
%

\end{document}
% ----- End of the document ----------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: The short answer is to use `\addtocontents`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149222/to-fix-alignment-in-text-added-to-table-of-contents?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C45.1667 for example.

Comment: @Alex could you update your example so it actually prints a couple of figures (just needs the `figure` environment with  a `\caption` in it) and add a few acronyms so this is easier to work off.  You can also ditch some of the irrelevant code like the bibliography-related commands.  Also note `\input` should be used instead of `\include` in the preamble.